# AddIn + MSAL.js vs certification policies

Tags: office-store

we are trying to validate an Outlook's AddIn that utilizes MSAL.js to authenticate the users using their Microsoft accounts. We need this feature because in our case, the users' emails are processed by our server. Therefore, we need offline access to accounts that are not linked to an organization.

The solution that works for most of the environments (web, desktop and mobile) we are able to test uses an Office Dialog, which for Outlook Web prompts the user for confirmation before opening the Dialog. However, it seems that this confirmation message is not customizable and it does not really follow some of the Microsoft design guidelines for AddIns.

Having said that, my question is: Is the default Office Dialog's confirmation message OK for the certification process?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "Questions asking about the store's terms & conditions or seeking customer service are off-topic."

Comment: Customer Service questions are off topic here. Please open a Customer Support ticket instead
https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport 
1.    Browse topics Category: Commercial Marketplace
2.    Topic: Certification issue
3.    Next step: Review solution

Comment: Thanks for point out the link for the Customer Support. We posted our question here, because in the submission feedback, it is mentioned that this is the place to solve validation issues:  "Contact us - We can help you resolve your validation issues more quickly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-store"

Comment: Well, that suggestion is simply wrong, but @OfficeStoreDeveloperComms does not seem to care about the bad user experience they create by explicitly directing people's off-topic-questions here.